# Loop function in R for different combination of variables

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I have a combination of pluses and minuses as follows:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 + + + + - - - -
 + + - - + + - -
 + - + - + - + -
```

I want to iterate each combination
for the code below

```
tbl44 <- tbl4 %>%
  top_n(280) %>%
  top_n(140) %>%
  top_n(70) %>%
  slice_head(n = 70)
```

For example, the first iteration must use `+280, +140. +70` and the second iteration must use `+280, +140. -70` and the third `+280, -140. +70` and so on for a total of 8 iterations.

And important thing is that after each iteration there is a need to exit. This means this is in the middle of the larger looping code.

I have come up with one possible idea. Improvement is welcome.

```
x = 1

mt <- list(list(280, 140, 70), list(280, 140, -70), list(280, -140, 70), list(280, -140, -70), 
           list(-280, 140, 70), list(-280, 140, -70), list(-280, -140, 70), list(-280, -140, -70))


while (x <= 8) {
a <- as.integer(mt[[x]][1])
b <- as.integer(mt[[x]][2])
c <- as.integer(mt[[x]][3])

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

tbl44 <- tbl4 %>%
  top_n(a) %>%
  top_n(b) %>%
  top_n(c) %>%
  slice_head(n = 70)

 x = x + 1
 break
}
```

Comment: Damina Oswald gives some starting point hence I am extending argument above.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question quite confusing, do you want to generate a list of combinations of numbers with the respective sign? If so, I would do it maybe like this:

```
signs <- data.frame(A = c("+", "+", "+"),
                    B = c("+", "+", "-"),
                    C = c("+", "-", "+"),
                    D = c("-", "+", "-"),
                    E = c("-", "-", "+"),
                    F = c("-", "-", "-"))
values <- c(280, 140, 70)

apply_signs <- function(signs, values){
   mapply(function(signs, values) do.call(get(signs), list(values)),
          signs = signs,
          values = values)
}
apply(signs, 2, apply_signs, values = values)
```

If I completely misunderstood you, please clarify and provide a reproducible problem.

Comment: The output generated by this code satisfies the requirement of combination but does not get into the iteration so we need an iteration part too that puts every combination into code.

Comment: I just don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, sorry. You give the example of a while-loop in your post, but you unconditionally stop it after the first run. If you want to have a loop, just replace the `apply` statement by a for- or while-loop.

Comment: check now, since I mentioned that the whole thing is part of a nested loop therefore `break` is used.

Comment: This is what I meant, you break your loop without any condition, meaning after the first iteration, the code ends already. I don't understand why you would then would want to iterate in the first place.